# Prefix in XML namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, xml-parsing

Is it possible to have prefix in XML namespace with colon?

Something like this

```
<root xmlns:x:y="...." />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results may vary depending on your XMl processor.

From the [NT-Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) definition:

```
The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML Names] assigns a meaning to names 
containing colon characters.
Therefore, authors should not use the colon in XML names except for 
namespace purposes, but XML processors must accept the colon as a name character.
```